# is There Any other way to use two different routes types in React Js, also this causing major issues in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, mern

I made a Movie App where there is two types of Routes, One is User Route And Another is Admin Route

in App.js

```
  import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  import { fetchSlider,fetchTrailer,fetchLastSlider, fetchLastTrailer } from './action/Trailer';
  import { useEffect } from 'react';
  import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

  import AdminRoute from './AdminRoute';
  import UserRoute from './UserRoute';
  import { getMovies } from './action/Movies';
  import { getAllMov } from './action/movies/Mov';
  import { getAllWebShow, getWebShow } from './action/movies/WebShow';
  import { getAllTvShow, getTvShow } from './action/movies/TvShow';
  import { getAllAnimeMovie, getAnimeMovie } from './action/movies/animated/Mov';
  import { getAllAnimeSeries, getAnimeSeries } from './action/movies/animated/WebShow';

  const App = () => {
    const dispatch=useDispatch()
    useEffect(()=>{
      dispatch(fetchSlider())
      dispatch(fetchTrailer())
      dispatch(fetchLastSlider())
      dispatch(fetchLastTrailer())
      dispatch(getMovies())
      dispatch(getAllMov())
      dispatch(getWebShow())
      dispatch(getAllWebShow())
      dispatch(getTvShow())
      dispatch(getAllTvShow())
      dispatch(getAllAnimeMovie())
      dispatch(getAllAnimeSeries())
      dispatch(getAnimeMovie())
      dispatch(getAnimeSeries())
    },[dispatch])
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={UserRoute} />
          <Route path='/admin' component={AdminRoute} />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  };

  export default App;
```

In UserRoute.js:

```
  import React from "react";
  import {Route, Switch,useLocation,BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

  import Navbar from "./components/User/Navbar/Navbar";
  import Footer from "./components/User/Footer/Footer";
  import Home from "./components/User/Home/Home";
  import Movies from "./components/User/Movies/Movies";
  import TrendingDetail from "./components/User/MovieDetail/MovieDetail";
  import Error404 from './components/Error404'

  import './stylesheet/css/Usermain.css'
  import RegLog from "./components/Admin/Auth/RegLog";
  import MovieDetail from "./components/User/Movies/MovieDetail";
  import WebDetails from "./components/User/WebSeries/WebDetails";
  import WebSeries from "./components/User/WebSeries/WebSeries";
  import SearchResult from "./components/User/searchResult/searchResult";

  // filter movie
  import ActionGenre from "./components/User/Movies/genre/Action";
  import Adventure from "./components/User/Movies/genre/Adventure";
  import Crime from "./components/User/Movies/genre/Crime";
  import Romance from "./components/User/Movies/genre/Romance";
  import Thriller from "./components/User/Movies/genre/Thriller";
  import SciFI from "./components/User/Movies/genre/SciFi";
  import Download from "./components/User/Movies/download";
  import TrendDownload from './components/User/MovieDetail/download'

  // filter webseires

  import webActionGenre from "./components/User/WebSeries/genre/Action"
  import webAdvenGenre from "./components/User/WebSeries/genre/Adventure"
  import webCrimeGenre from "./components/User/WebSeries/genre/Crime"
  import webRomanceGenre from "./components/User/WebSeries/genre/Romance"
  import webSciFiGenre from "./components/User/WebSeries/genre/SciFi"
  import webThrillerGenre from "./components/User/WebSeries/genre/Thriller"
  import Secondary from "./components/User/WebSeries/download/secondary";
  import PrimaryWeb from "./components/User/WebSeries/download/download";

  // Tv Shows
  import TvSeries from "./components/User/TvShow/TvSeries";
  import TvDetail from "./components/User/TvShow/TvDetails";
  import SecondaryTv from "./components/User/TvShow/download/secondary";
  import PrimaryTv from './components/User/TvShow/download/download'

  import filterTvAction from './components/User/TvShow/genre/Action'
  import filterTvAdven from './components/User/TvShow/genre/Adventure'
  import filterTvCrime from './components/User/TvShow/genre/Crime'
  import filterTvRomance from './components/User/TvShow/genre/Romance'
  import filterTvScifi from './components/User/TvShow/genre/SciFi'
  import filterTvThriller from './components/User/TvShow/genre/Thriller'


  const UserRoute = () => {
      const {pathname}=useLocation()
      const e=pathname
      const url='/admin'
      const paths = e===`${url}` || e===`${url}/movies` || e===`${url}/webseries` || e===`${url}/tvshow` || e===`${url}/animatedweb` || e===`${url}/animated`  || e===`${url}/trending` || e===`${url}/download`
      const Auths= e===`${url}/signin` || e===`${url}/signup` || e=== `${url}/pass`
      const Expaths= e===`${url}/mobtrailer`
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        {(paths || Auths || Expaths ? null : <Navbar />)}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path='/search' component={SearchResult} />
          {/* movies */}
          <Route path='/movdetails/:id' component={MovieDetail} />
          <Route exact path="/movies" component={Movies} />
          <Route path='/movie/genre/action' component={ActionGenre} />
          <Route path='/movie/genre/adventure' component={Adventure} />
          <Route path='/movie/genre/crime' component={Crime} />
          <Route path='/movie/genre/romance' component={Romance} />
          <Route path='/movie/genre/thriller' component={Thriller} />
          <Route path='/movie/genre/scifi' component={SciFI} />
          <Route path='/download/movies/:id' component={Download} />
          
          <Route path='/download/trendmovies/:id' component={TrendDownload} />
          <Route path="/details/:id" component={TrendingDetail} />

          {/* webseries */}
          <Route exact path="/webshow" component={WebSeries} />
          <Route path='/webshowdetails/:id' component={WebDetails} />
          <Route path='/webshows/genre/action' component={webActionGenre} />
          <Route path='/webshows/genre/adventure' component={webAdvenGenre} />
          <Route path='/webshows/genre/crime' component={webCrimeGenre} />
          <Route path='/webshows/genre/romance' component={webRomanceGenre} />
          <Route path='/webshows/genre/scifi' component={webSciFiGenre} />
          <Route path='/webshows/genre/thriller' component={webThrillerGenre} />
          <Route path='/secondary/download/webshow/:id' component={Secondary} />
          <Route path='/download/webshow/:id' component={PrimaryWeb} />

          {/* TvShow */}
          <Route exact path='/tvshow' component={TvSeries} />
          <Route path='/tvshowdetails/:id' component={TvDetail} />
          <Route path='/tvshows/genre/action' component={filterTvAction} />
          <Route path='/tvshows/genre/adventure' component={filterTvAdven} />
          <Route path='/tvshows/genre/crime' component={filterTvCrime} />
          <Route path='/tvshows/genre/romance' component={filterTvRomance} />
          <Route path='/tvshows/genre/scifi' component={filterTvScifi} />
          <Route path='/tvshows/genre/thriller' component={filterTvThriller} />
          <Route path='/secondary/download/tvshow/:id' component={SecondaryTv} />
          <Route path='/download/tvshow/:id' component={PrimaryTv} />

          {/* Animated  */}
          {/* <Route path='/animated' component={AnimeMovie} /> */}
          
          <Route path='/pass' component={RegLog} />
          {(paths || Auths || Expaths ? null : <Route component={Error404} />)}
        </Switch>
        {(paths || Auths || Expaths ? null : <Footer />)}
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };

  export default UserRoute;
```

in AdminRoute.js :

```
  import React from "react";
  import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch, useLocation, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
  import Admin from "./components/Admin/Home/Admin";
  import AdminNav from "./components/Admin/Navbar/Navbar";
  import AdminLog from "./components/Admin/Auth/AdminLog";
  import AdminReg from "./components/Admin/Auth/AdminReg";
  import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
  // StyleSheet
  import "./stylesheet/css/Adminmain.css";
  import RegLog from "./components/Admin/Auth/RegLog";

  import AdminMovies from "./components/Admin/AdminMovies/Trending/AdminMovies";
  import AdminMovie from "./components/Admin/AdminMovies/movies/AdminMovies";
  import AdminWebSeries from "./components/Admin/AdminMovies/webseries/AdminMovies";
  import AdminTvShow from "./components/Admin/AdminMovies/tvShow/AdminMovies";

  const AdminRoute = () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Adminprofile"))
    const supAd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SupAd'))
    
    const { path } = useRouteMatch();
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    
    const notshow = pathname === "/admin/signin" || pathname === "/admin/signup" || pathname==="/admin/pass";
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        {user ? (
          <>
            {notshow ? null : <AdminNav />}
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`${path}`} component={Admin} />
            <Route path={`${path}/trending`} component={AdminMovies} />
            <Route path={`${path}/movies`} component={AdminMovie} />
            <Route path={`${path}/webseries`} component={AdminWebSeries} />
            <Route path={`${path}/tvshow`} component={AdminTvShow} />
            {/* <Route path={`${path}/animated`} component={AdminAnimatedMovie} /> */}
            {/* <Route path={`${path}/animatedweb`} component={AdminAnimatedSeries} /> */}
          </Switch>
          </>
        ) : (notshow ? null : <Redirect to='/' /> ) }
        
        <Route path={`${path}/pass`} component={RegLog} /> 
        <Route path={`${path}/signin`} component={AdminLog} />
        
        <Route path={`${path}/signup`}>
          { supAd ? <AdminReg /> : <Redirect to='/' />} 
        </Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };

  export default AdminRoute;
```

Now the problem is when I am opening admin routes its showing black page.

and if I congfiguring different settings in app then its start showing black page in User Routes

Also my App gets freezes in mobile devices no touches working in mobile devices

is there any way to solve this bug ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It sounds like you've got a lot of things going on that you're trying to troubleshoot, so it might be hard to get help. I'd recommend breaking it down into smaller problems. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on that issue, but that issue was with me also just add the keyword `exact` before path in your app.js file. And also do let me know that did it solve your Problem??

Comment: as I mentioned I also tried this but it didn't resolve this error

Comment: I want you to try and comment out your entire code in the admin route and just return "hello world" so that we can know that Is something in Your code of Admin Route causing the page to freeze or something is wrong with app.js, so that half of our problems could be eliminated